# Can I activate a different version of Windows using an OEM key?

Tags: windows-8.1, reinstall

I wanted to reinstall Windows on my laptop, which came with Windows 8.1 Pro. I accidentally reinstalled it using a non-Pro install medium. Now Windows won't activate with the key from my initial installation. It won't let me upgrade to pro either.

Is there any way I can activate short of reinstalling again with an 8.1 Pro medium?

Comment: Short answer: no.

Comment: Reinstall using the correct media.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot. But the easiest solution is probably also the best.

Use a windows 8.1 Pro install medium to perform an update. It will keep your settings etc in tact but change the version of windows.

After that you will be able to activate windows.

To perform an update, insert the cd while you are in windows and run the setup. It will ask you to update that version of windows.

Do note, this only works if you go from a lower version to a higher version. So if you installed an enterprise version, it won't work.

Comment: To whomever gave me a downvote: please leave a comment as to why this information is incorrect and I happily make changes.

Answer (score -2):

If your computer came with an OEM genuine Windows 8.1 pro, there should be an embedded unique key in the BIOS. You can find the key using [this open source software.](https://github.com/christian-korneck/get_win8key#files) then try to upgrade with this key.

Comment: Please reread the question.